# How to type Japanese with kana input in a たていすかん (109-key) layout using a 104-key ANSI layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, typing, japanese

I want to practice typing with a kana input たていすかん keyboard layout, however I don't have an 109-key たていすかん Japanese keyboard.

After browsing amazon.co.jp, I found that a lot of QWERTY/104-key keyboards are actually sold in Japan, and they have specific key combinations to emulate the 変換、無変換、半角 / 全角 / 漢字、and ひらがな / カタカナ / ローマ字 keys.

I'm an Ubuntu Linux user. Is there a way to make my computer treat my 104-key layout as an 109-key one, and allow me to use kana input?

Answer (score 0):

Me, too. "Kana input" faction. I have two solutions.
たていすかん is old JIS standard so you can't use JIS' たていすかん in "Model M  101/104 keys keyboard".

There's someone called Tsutomu Kawamura that uploaded his solution for "Kana input" issue. "Model M  101/104 keys keyboard" remapped image exchanging the "Model M  106/109 keys keyboard", and other solutions, and some programs on Reddit.

https://medium.com/@cognitom/good-bye-japanese-keyboard-9b0418f32e2c

If you're detailed about programming or "Microsoft's Windows"' features then you could adopt his solution. Download his program from Reddit, remapping...

And, onther one is mine that I'm using, now. This kind of keymap is also different from "Kawamura's 三角かな配列 and「はんそく」カナ配列". Although it's easier, it looks a little picky.
I'm using the Microsoft IME(Windows 10's default IME) instead of Kawamura's method. I don't want to get Google IME downloaded from net because of synchronization of user's device data. And there isn't any keymap reference for Microsoft IME, unfortunately(WTF??). But there're some photos for Microsoft IME 104 keys Kana input layout.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18LaLjjdr5J6Ad2vMu8hkooH9b7S2Wj9Z/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1y3oABSz5MLL7hRVqomfy8LgNsU1zC0/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YkiiViwmAFGYEICpSqopIUUR96AtmkPb/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cy1yNX9Ojt_cPZQdKdF_V-jVdAPssR7s/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1foeH4_Mp_82eZ09rplWVGqFWy0OF8KH_/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i2o10bHV9twAQWgj4ynJpYwb0_VRSfOI/view?usp=sharing
Okay, I used the highest resolution image from the Internet.

I just thought he was in IBM's OADG(PC Open Architecture Developers' Group, PCオープン・アーキテクチャー推進協議会, an international official group that manages keyboard layout) before and he keeps a cafe called "OpenSource Cafe, Shimokitazawa" in Tokyo that provides a programming coworking environment. So you could use his solution without needing to so worry about the authority.
But for me, I like my solution instead of Kawamura's.